# Stack Exchange History book?

Tags: discussion

As a big fan of the Middle Ages ( although a total amateur),  I am mesmerized by the inventivity of the questions (and throughliness of the  answers) in that domain on SE History.

Why isn't there a book with the questions and best answers? Is this because there was never an interest in publishing one? Or due to copyright issues? Or something else?

My professional area is information security and the relevant stack exchange site is full of excellent content but I do not feel that it would be as interesting in a book as is history.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make such a book, you are perfectly fine to do so. All stack exchange content is provided under CC-BY-SA by their authors (just scroll to the bottom on any page) so in theory, as long as you fulfil the terms of that license, you can repackage and distribute the content in any way you like.

As a practical consideration, there is no guarantee that the content was produced legally. People often provide content like quotes and images without the proper attribution, or sourced with permission from the rights holders. Any book publisher wishing to reuse stack exchange user contributions would have to vet all the content before publishing.

Comment: Is that meant to be "sourced with*out* permission"?